# How to set up self-hosted video.js player with playlist?

Tags: video.js

**Desired Behaviour**

- A responsive video.js player with playlist ([official demo here](http://videojs.com/advanced/))
- in a Google Apps Script environment
- with firewall restrictions, which therefore requires self-hosted files.

The `Google Apps Script application behind a firewall` condition is irrelevant, apart from the fact that it means I need to know exactly what files are required so that I can add them individually to the Google Apps Script project.

**What I've Tried**

There is a tutorial here:

http://blog.videojs.com/Video-js-5-s-fluid-mode-and-playlist-picker/

Which culminates in the following HTML and CSS:

**HTML**

```
<section class="main-preview-player">
  <video id="preview-player" class="video-js vjs-fluid" controls preload="auto" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
  </video>
  <div class="playlist-container  preview-player-dimensions vjs-fluid">
    <ol class="vjs-playlist"></ol>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-preview-player {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.video-js,
.playlist-container {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 150px;
  height: 0;
}
.video-js {
  flex: 3 1 70%;
}
.playlist-container {
  flex: 1 1 30%;
}
.vjs-playlist {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

It also states:

> For this example, We’re using the [videojs-playlist-ui](https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-playlist-ui) and
>   [videojs-playlist](https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-playlist) plugins for the playlist functionality

But it doesn't say *how* to implement those plugins.

The tutorials on the plugin pages (linked above) are confusing to me because they either refer to installing things via `node`, or to `dist` directories that I can't find in the github repo's.

**jsFiddle**

I've made a start on recreating the scenario in [a jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/zuf292p4/) and have added the following files as resources:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/5.15.1/video.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/5.15.1/video-js.css

It obviously requires the plugin files as well, but I don't know:

- Which files need to be added
- How they should be referenced

Comment: did you found any working solution?

Comment: Did you get a fully working solution? I am looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you

https://jsfiddle.net/c5xqfekp/

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/5.15.1/video.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/5.15.1/video.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/5.15.1/video.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/5.15.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="main-preview-player">
  <div id="preview-player" class="video-js vjs-fluid vjs-paused preview-player-dimensions vjs-workinghover vjs-error vjs-controls-disabled vjs-user-inactive" controls preload="auto" crossorigin="anonymous" role="region">
    <video id="preview-player_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" poster="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png" src=" //vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4">
      <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
      </p>
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="playlist-container  preview-player-dimensions vjs-fluid">
    <ol class="vjs-playlist"></ol>
  </div>
</section>
```

If I'm not wrong you may have confused with the div for the player and the source elements providing the data what should be shown video.

Comment: The player at the jsFiddle above seems to not function at all?